How to switch between apps and automatically return to my app in swift?
Is it possible for me to develop an iOS application using Swift? The application will contain a button, if this button is clicked it will redirect to the YouTube app, search for a specific keyword provided by my application, and automatically play the first result. Once I begin playing, the app is able to automatically bring me back to my previous location within the app. Please note that this is an automatic process and no further action is needed.
I discovered that YouTube has its own Software Development Kit, however, it appears unable to integrate this functionality.
Could you share some thoughts with me?

It is easy to call YouTube r another app using url. But returning back needs to add the functionality in YouTube app. Look at this answer

In a word, no. iOS does not let apps control the system or other apps. if the Youtube app has a custom URL scheme and the user has it installed, you could use an openURL call to open a video in the other app, but there is no way to have control return to your app afterwords. I imagine the Youtube SDK will allow you to play Youtube videos within your app however, in which case you can do everything in your app and don't need to launch the other app.

The only way to do closest thing is to open browser page in your app and open youtube in browser. In this case all will be in one app - in your's app.
Instead of browser you can use SwuftUI youtube control that embed videoplayer into your interface: https://github.com/SvenTiigi/YouTubePlayerKit
And to return to your main view all you need is to close sheet.
Similar way is implemented in Telegram app when user trying to open any link via mobile phone version of Telegram.
